# Invisible Connection String in MS EL Logging Configuration

Tags: logging, configuration, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

Masters.

I'm supposed to implement MS EL's logging framework with database as a sink. I am done with the code blocks. All I have to do is make it run and log. But when I checked on the given logging configuration, it's quite different from the one you get with the EntLib Config - it doesn't have a connection string. I could not find it within the given app.config, although its listener has a databaseInstanceName. I've been wondering, is there another way of configuring database logging without placing the connection string within the app.config?

Thank you.

Comment: How your configuration "quite different"? Posting the config might help.

Comment: It doesn't have a connection string for the databaseInstance. But it's okay now. The configuration initially given to me wasn't actually correct. Thanks!